# Inserting space between a letter and a number in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

I am working on formatting a list of addresses like:

```
New york city23 b
Miami 355c
```

I need them to look like

```
New York City 23 B
Miami 355 C
```

The problem is adding space before and after the letter+number combination. I came up with the following regex to highlight the troubled areas:

```
/\p{L}\d|\d\p{L}/
```

But am missing the logic to actually put a space between those. Right now the code looks like

```
"moscow city46 d".titleize.gsub(/\p{L}\d|\d\p{L}/, ' \0')
# titleize is a Rails method
```

which outputs

```
Moscow Cit y46 D
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you used `titleize` I'm assuming you don't mind using other ActiveSupport methods. It's not as "clever" as some, but [`String#squish`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-squish), which replaces runs of consecutive whitespace with a single space, makes for a pretty simple solution:

```
str.gsub(/\d+/, ' \0 ').squish.titleize
```

Ruby (sans Rails) has a similar [`String#squeeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze) method, but unlike `squish` it doesn't trim leading and trailing whitespace, so it has to be combined with [`String#strip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-strip).

Comment: It's actually much cleverer than the other solutions IMHO. Note: `titleize` is an ActiveSupport method.

Answer (score 5):

Use lookarounds and replace with a single space:

```
.gsub(/(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})/, ' ')
```

The `(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})` regex will match 2 locations:

- `(?<=\p{L})(?=\d)` - location between a letter and a digit
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\d)(?=\p{L})` - location between a digit and a letter.

So, the space will be just "inserted" in between the digit or letter.

Answer (score 2):

```
'New york city23 b'.scan(/\D+|\d+/).flat_map(&:split).map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  # => "New York City 23 B"
```

Comment: Why not split like this: `"moscow city46 d".split(/ |(\d+)/).map(&:capitalize).join(' ')` or something similar.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I find it easier to reason that my tokens are either digits or non-digits. Also you have to be mindful of why you needed to add it a group and so on.

Comment: ✅, `"New york city23 b\nMiami 355c".scan....join(' ') #=> "New York City 23 B Miami 355 C"`. This is, the newline is missing. Nor is @Casimir's suggestion not quite right. Play with both and I'm sure you'll find a fix.

Comment: @CarySwoveland, I'll leave it to the reader if it's a situation they are concerned with.

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-regex pure-Ruby solution.

```
cities =<<-_
New york city23 b
Miami 355c
_

cities.each_char.each_cons(2).map do |a,b|
  str = a+b
  r = /[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]/
  str =~ r || str.reverse =~ r ? "#{a} " : a
end.join.split.map(&:capitalize).join(' ')
  #=> "New York City 23 B Miami 355 C"
```